# Webpack devServer CORS proxy for back-end api

Tags: node.js, webpack, proxy, cors

I'd like to establish a cors-proxy for back-end restful API with Webpack devServer. The real pattern might be as below:

```
https://localhost:3000/back-end/restful/api
```

`localhost:3000` opened by Webpack devServer, `https://back-end/restful/api` is the back-end api. No matter `get` `post` `put` `delete` all could be forwarded with such a pattern. Is there any solution to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

### Context

What you need is a [`middleware`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). And Express provides one to work with [`CORS`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

### Examples

Practical usage examples, based on your endpoint, would be:

#### Defined for any route

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/back-end/restful/api', function (req, res, next) {
  // Write your logic here
  // ie:
  res.json({ msg: 'CORS-enabled!' })
});
```

#### Defined for some routes

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.get('/back-end/restful/api', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  // Write your logic here
  // ie:
  res.json({ msg: 'CORS-enabled!' })
});
```

Further documentation at [Express's CORS project](https://github.com/expressjs/cors).